# Test Mode in Authorize.net

Tags: magento-1.9, authorize.net

I am want to check Authorize is working or not

I change Test Mode to Yes in configuration and i want to use with test credit numbers

I have added Live Authorize.net details

In configuration Authorize only is selected and Capture will be done after so when i try to invoice it is throwing error

> Gateway error: (TESTMODE) Credit card number is required.

It is not sandbox account

Can anyone suggest is it possible to test with test card with live account?

Answer (score 0):

No test card detail will not work with the live site . Test card detail will work with sandbox.